# Joomla 3+ how to make artcile title as a panel

Tags: php, css, content-management-system, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

How to make joomla 3 article title to be shown as per like in attachment.
Looking for any module or css to do that.

Panel Title

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS, in this case you need something called **ribbon**.

First you need select the Title for the Article, add a background color and then the ribbon code, you can inspect the source code of your page with some inspector tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or similar, a tool like this will be of great utility, don't forget to add your custom CSS in your main css file.

Here you have two examples:

- [CSS powered ribbons the clean way](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/css-powered-ribbons-the-clean-way/)
- [How to Create CSS3 Ribbons Without Images](https://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-ribbons/)

Comment: COOL.Thanks bro. I did use another css tricks to solve my issue.